# How to split events apply different map on each group and then merge them back

Tags: java, grouping, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux

I have a list of items coming which has 2 types of ids. I need to group them into 2 and then for one group call another method which will enrich the id and provide a different id and for the other group just return the same. I need to merge both the groups together into single stream after the above action. But when I apply `map` it returns `Flux<Object>` and loosing the type information.

```
Flux.fromIterable(events)
         .map(event -> serializer.deserialize(event, Payload.class))
         .filter(Optional::isPresent)
         .map(Optional::get)   //Flux<Event>
         .groupBy(event -> event.getIdType()) //There are only 2 types
         .concatMap(group -> group.map(event -> {
             if(group.key().equals(IdType.SEC_ID.getValue())) {
                 //Enrich and use
                 return enricher.enrich(List.of(event)); //return Flux<Event>
             }
             else {
                 //Just use them as such
                 return event;
             }
         })) //Returns Flux<Object> why is not returning Flux<Event>
```

How to merge them now?

Answer (score 0):

A short answer:
You get `Flux<Object>` because from `group.map` you return either `Event` either `Flux<Event>`, and their common parent class is Object. A quick fix is `group.flatMap` + `Mono.just()`:

```
     .concatMap(group -> group.flatMap(event -> {
         if(group.key().equals(IdType.SEC_ID.getValue())) {
             //Enrich and use
             return enricher.enrich(List.of(event)); //return Flux<Event>
         }
         else {
             //Just use them as such
             return Mono.just(event);
         }
     }))
```

However, since you are enriching event's one by one (`List.of(event)`) do you really need grouping and `concatMap`? You can do it easier:

```
    Flux.fromIterable(events)
            .map(event -> serializer.deserialize(event, Payload.class))
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)   //Flux<Event>
            .flatMap(event -> {
                if(event.getIdType().equals(IdType.SEC_ID.getValue())) {
                    return enricher.enrich(List.of(event)); //return Flux<Event>
                }
                else {
                    //Just use them as such
                    return Mono.just(event);
                }
            }); //Returns Flux<Event>
```

If you want to reduce it to single `enricher` call providing a complete List of events, then you can do it like that:

```
            Flux.fromIterable(List.of(new Event()))
                    .map(event -> serializer.deserialize(event, Payload.class))
                    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                    .map(Optional::get)   //Flux<Event>
                    .groupBy(Event::getIdType)
                    .concatMap(group -> {
                        if (group.key().equals(IdType.SEC_ID.getValue())) {
                            //Enrich and use
                            return group.collectList()
                                    .flatMapMany(enricher::enrich);
                        } else {
                            //Just use them as such
                            return group;
                        }
                    });
```

Be cautious, list of `SEC_ID` events will be collected in memory.

Comment: I want grouping because I don't want to enrich event by event but a list of events since enriching is costly

Comment: Then use the last approach